# Spring Security 4 2FA

Tags: spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

so I am trying to secure a web application that I built using spring mvc and security. I currently have the basic username and password from a normal custom login page working using a custom authentication provider to provide the populated authentication object that is verified against a database. What I am wondering is how do I implement a second phase of logging in that uses TOTP? I can get the the TOTP issuing and verification to work, but am unsure how to modify spring security to accept a change to authorization via a form submission of the token on a page other then the login page I've specified.

Comment: There are many ways to do it.  The simplest is to: a. Allow anonymous access to just the Login page;  b. Allow access only to authenticated users to the OTP Code Entry page;  c. Allow access only to authenticated users with a particular role to all other pages.  Then, redirect the user to the OTP Code Entry page on successful login.  On successful OTP entry, grant the mandatory role to the user.  For a sample implementation of this strategy see [this post](http://altfatterz.blogspot.in/2014/02/two-factor-authentication-with-spring.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically what I ended up doing was using the authy api(http://docs.authy.com/) to do the TOTP delivery and verification. After the initial login I grant them ROLE_PRE_AUTH and then send them to a protected page to process the TOTP. I then used

```
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(auth.getAuthorities());
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        Authentication newAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(auth.getPrincipal(), auth.getCredentials(), authorities);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(newAuth);
```

to update the roles for the user once I verified that they had a valid TOTP.

Comment: Here is a link to the documentation covering it http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#tech-intro-sec-context-persistence