# Elegant solution for TOTP or other multi-factor authentication in a Grails application?

Tags: authentication, grails, spring-security, multi-factor-authentication

I was surprised to see no obvious plugin or setting to enable any type of multi-factor authentication in Grails.  Is there an elegant solution available?  I would ideally like to implement a [TOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm) solution for use with apps like Google Authenticator or standalone fobs, but would consider a text message based solution also.

The solution must play nicely with and augment the built in Spring Security authentication.

Comment: did you try RFC, there is sample code for TOTP and HOTP algorithm,
also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31734110/spring-security-4-2fa

Comment: I started researching this a while back but needed to focus on getting the security plugins working with Grails 3. If you google 'spring security totp' you'll find a bunch of non-Grails info, and if you want to create a plugin I'd be willing to help out.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith sounds like a plan.  Once we implement I'll get in touch as to best way to exctract to a generic plugin.  Could be a while unfortunately so if anything useful is available please add an answer

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar in a web application I built. I couldn't find anything as clean as a straight up plugin, but I was able to still integrate it with spring security.

So basically what I ended up doing was using the authy api(http://docs.authy.com/ I am sure you could find something similar with google auth) to do the TOTP delivery and verification. After the initial login I grant them ROLE_PRE_AUTH and then send them to a protected page to process the TOTP. I then used

```
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(auth.getAuthorities());
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    Authentication newAuth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(auth.getPrincipal(), auth.getCredentials(), authorities);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(newAuth);
```

to update the roles for the user once I verified (again using the api available) that they had a valid TOTP. So basically you want to create a class to do this verification and only after it runs do you want to navigate to the next page (which they now have authority to visit)

Comment: Thanks, good place to start if I end up having to roll my own.

Comment: I understand that this answer is a good start to implement TOTP. However this was applicable for Oct 2015 (long time back). @Burt Beckwith Later on, was there anything added in the plugin for easing this out?